# What is a .ripple-box in the gnome.css?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

I see this CSS class selector `.ripple-box{}` in the `/usr/shar/gnome-shell/theme.gnome.css` file. Which part of the gnome shell appearance does it affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [search results on codesearch.debian.net](https://sources.debian.org/src/gnome-shell-extensions/3.34.2-1/data/gnome-shell-sass/_common.scss/?hl=1232#L1232) for this CSS class we have the following explanation:

> ```
> // Activities Ripples
> .ripple-box {
> ...
> }
> .ripple-box:rtl { ... } // just a simple change to the border radius position
> ```

So it changes the style of the Desktop's corners when activated. That is, when the mouse pointer moves to the top left (or right) corner of the desktop environment, which is where the GNOME <kbd>Activities</kbd> button is located on the Desktop Top Menu Bar, the appearance of `.ripple-box{}`  will be shown.

Comment: I have proposed a bit more detail to your answer address my question. Pls check and amend according. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, @SunBear!